# Installing a remote videobridge to an existing jitsi-meet installation. SSL error

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, jitsi-meet, prosody-im

I've a working standard jitsi-meet install on a single VM. I now want to "detach" the videobridge2 (JVB) from this VM setup and install it on another machine (to use only https 443 port).

I watched [this outdated tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=521&v=LyGV4uW8km8&feature=emb_logo) and understood a bit how it works under the hood.
I stumbled upon [this more recent wiki](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/wiki/jitsi-meet-load-balancing-installation-Ubuntu-18.04-with-MUC-and-JID) and decided to follow it.

While I'm unsure to have properly followed it perfectly (because some parts were not very explicit to me), I have this error in my distant JVB logs:

```
2020-05-16 14:46:15.192 WARNING: [39] [hostname=sub.mydomain.tld id=shard] MucClient$1.connectionClosedOnError#295: Closed on error:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1967)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:331)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:325)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1688)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:226)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1082)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:1010)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1079)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1388)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPTCPConnection.java:810)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$1200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:151)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1071)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1000)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1016)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I'm understanding correctly, the distant JVB tries to connect to my jitsi-meet VM prosody to receive traffic. But according to the above logs, it seems that there is a certificate problem with the MUC connexion. I found [this old thread](https://community.jitsi.org/t/questions-about-the-prosody-certificates/16679) on the community forum saying there is no need to worry about all these self-signed certificates, but I'm feeling that I should try to install proper certificates?

Does someone here, recently managed to install multiple JVB instances to a jitsi-meet install and could lighten me a bit here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the certificate verification in your remote JVB. In your remote JVB `/etc/jitsi/videobridge/sip-communicator.properties` file add one more parameter

```
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.DISABLE_CERTIFICATE_VERIFICATION=true
```

It's updated now in their [wiki](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/wiki/jitsi-meet-load-balancing-installation-Ubuntu-18.04-with-MUC-and-JID) as well.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your answer. I saw that in the wiki, but I'm not sure this is an appropriate answer. Is that not a security leak to disable ssl verification? I mean, my question was rather "how to connect securely a remote JVB machine" rather than "how to connect it, despite any security concerns" ;)